# CNTK Run Time Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, cntk

I am trying a simple lstm network in cntk and I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-d0a0e4f580aa> in <module>()
      6         trainer.train_minibatch({x: x1, l: y1})
      7     if epoch % (EPOCHS / 10) == 0:
----> 8         training_loss = trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average
      9         loss_summary.append(training_loss)
     10         print("epoch: {}, loss: {:.5f}".format(epoch, training_loss))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\cntk\train\trainer.pyc in previous_minibatch_loss_average(self)
    285         The average training loss per sample for the last minibatch trained
    286         '''
--> 287         return super(Trainer, self).previous_minibatch_loss_average()
    288 
    289     @property

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.pyc in previous_minibatch_loss_average(self)
   2516 
   2517     def previous_minibatch_loss_average(self):
-> 2518         return _cntk_py.Trainer_previous_minibatch_loss_average(self)
   2519 
   2520     def previous_minibatch_evaluation_average(self):

RuntimeError: There was no preceeding call to TrainMinibatch or the minibatch was empty.

[CALL STACK]
    > CNTK::Trainer::  PreviousMinibatchLossAverage
    - 00007FFFA932A5F6 (SymFromAddr() error: Attempt to access invalid address.)
    - PyCFunction_Call
    - PyEval_GetGlobals
    - PyEval_EvalFrameEx
    - PyEval_GetFuncDesc
    - PyEval_GetGlobals
    - PyEval_EvalFrameEx
    - PyEval_EvalCodeEx
    - PyFunction_SetClosure
    - PyObject_Call (x2)
    - PyObject_CallFunction
    - PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict
    - PyType_Lookup
    - PyEval_EvalFrameEx
```

The relevant code is:

```
# train
loss_summary = []
start = time.time()
for epoch in range(0, EPOCHS):
    for x1, y1 in next_batch(x_train, y_train):
        trainer.train_minibatch({x: x1, l: y1})
    if epoch % (EPOCHS / 10) == 0:
        training_loss = trainer.previous_minibatch_loss_average
        loss_summary.append(training_loss)
        print("epoch: {}, loss: {:.5f}".format(epoch, training_loss))
```

Now, I am stuck at this for hours now and cant understand what is happening. I am following a tutorial at https://notebooks.azure.com/cntk/libraries/tutorials/html/CNTK_106A_LSTM_Timeseries_with_Simulated_Data.ipynb and searching google also is not helping.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea: Could it be, that your for (next minibatch) loop is never executed?

I would try to debug it using pdb. Just `import pdb`at the top of your jupyter cell and add a `pdb.set_trace()` before the `for x1, y1 ..` loop. Run the cell. You can use step (s) to go into the methods or use next (n) to go forward. That could maybe help you to analyse the trace and you can use prints in pdb to proof the variables.